# Engineering a pulley system to make an object move when gate is opened

Tags: design, pulleys

****Updated image attached based on @Translators suggestion comment****
Hi I am looking to make a movable wood cutout via a pulley system on the back my gate/fence (a monkey that tips a top hat when gate is opened and puts top hat back on head when gate is closed). The only part that would move via the pulley is the arm holding the top hat. What kind of pulley system/setup would I need to make  this work?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The center eye-hook in your new sketch is not correct. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thankyou for spotting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're most of the way there.

[image]

*Figure 1. Rear view of gate, fence and arm.*

The main tricks here are:

- Set up the arm so that it always falls under gravity. Add weight at the elbow if required.
- Figure out how much motion you want at the point where the string is tied to the arm.
- If the gate is opened 90° the horizontal string length will be 70% of its value when the gate is closed. (The gate, fence and string will form a right angled triangle and Pythagoras says that if the two sides are 1 unit long then the hypotenuse (the string) will be $ \sqrt {1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt 2 = 0.7 $.) That means that the string vertical will move 30% of the horizontal length when the gate is closed.

e.g. We want 200 mm movement on the end of the arm:

- 200 mm = 30% of horizontal string.
- String length = 200 × 100 / 30 = 666 mm.
- Distance from hinge to tie point and pulley point = 333 mm.

I think a simple eye-hook might suffice rather than a pulley but that depends on the weight of the arm.

If you want to limit the motion  when the gate opens then tie a stopper to the horizontal string so that at the required point it bumps into the pulley and won't let the arm drop any further. The horizontal string will then sag.

[image]

*Figure 2. Adding a ring in the position circled will cause the mechanism to fail as there will be no change in length between gate closed and gate open.*

I can see that my addition of the hinge (drawn before the string) may have caused some confusion as the string passes over the top of the pin.

Comment: Thanks Translator ..this is a great setup, since the cutout will be on the moving gate opposite side to the string I could move the hook eyes to the bottom of the fence then through a hole in the gate have the pull anchor come up hidden behind the body to a pivot.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to make it work. I assumed that the bear would be above the gate. I would probably run the arm pivot shaft through the bear and the gate and conceal the string and lever arm behind the gate. It would be stronger but would leave a hole in the gate which you may not like.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the cable anchor point over the word "fence" in the drawing and the dot on the gate as a pulley location, the distance between the two is reduced as the gate is opened. Rather than placing a pulley at the marked location, a capstan would provide rotational movement if the loose end of the cable has a weight. As the distance is reduced by opening, the falling weight would cause the capstan to turn, moving the arm that is attached.

If a weight on the gate is unacceptable, route the cable around the capstan, then back to the fence point, with another pulley and weight to provide the same capability. This method is likely preferable, as it prevents a swinging gate and a swinging weight, as well as reducing the mass on the gate.

[image: monkey arm gate capstan]

The top panel is a rough creation of a cable attached to a cone shaped weight passing over a pulley, then around the capstan. Use your imagination to envision that the cable wraps around the capstan more than once and that the axle for the capstan is the same as the axle for the arm visible in the background. After looping around the capstan, the cable is anchored on the fixed panel of the fence.

Imagination is again required to envision the same cable routing for the bottom panel. My artistic and creation skills were nearly exhausted at this point. The cable will shorten as the gate is opened, but remains in plane with the pulley for the weight and in plane with the capstan. The distance is shortened by the opening gate, allowing the weight to pull the cable downward, rotating the capstan in the direction of the weight, raising the arm.

None of this is to scale and barely represents the real world. Many variations are possible, including additional pulleys on both panels, which would increase the cable travel as the gate transits. Larger or smaller diameter capstans will change the travel. Adding a counterweight arm on the head of the capstan opposite to the monkey arm will reduce the amount of force necessary to lift the arm.

Someone with Solidworks or Fusion 360 skills could possible recreate this and provide animation, but that's out of my league.

It should be noted that this specific arrangement will also create a form of power assist to the gate, as it will have force applied by the weight, in the direction of opening. Keeping the arm balanced will allow for a lighter weight and reduced chance of overpowering the person moving the gate.

Comment: Thankyou fred_dot_u  ,as someone that doesn't have an engineering background what would this capstan setup look like like in a drawn diagram?